# How to use an external package?

Tags: packages

I'm using Tex 2.9 and Texmaker, My supervisor send me the template file with this commands:

```
\usepackage{XThesis} %DAL Thesis Style
\usepackage{XTocinc} %Include Table of Contents as the first entry in TOC
%                     Faculty of Grad Studies insists on this!?
```

Normally I had error messages because I hadn't these packages installed on my system.

How can I get these packages and install them manually?

Comment: these are not "standard" packages.  your supervisor should have told you where to get them.  as for installation, just put them into the area you are working in, and latex will find them.

Comment: Google for `XThesis.sty` and `XTocinc.sty`. The names are rather unique, so chances are high that what you find are actually the right style files. It may be outdated versions, though, so the preferred variant is to ask the supervisor, as Barbara proposes.

Comment: When you have the packages, you can read this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 2):

## XThesis

As user [gernot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/110998/gernot) recommended, I looked for the package using Google.
 - The result is a GitHub project with the title *Undergrad thesis at Reed College* ([link](https://github.com/atkm/thesis)).
 - I downloaded the project as you can see in the screenshot.

[image]

- Then you have a ZIP file that you just need to unzip.
- Since the file `XThesis.sty` is in the same folder as the main file, laTeX automatically will find it.

[image]

## XTocinc

- Searching for `XTocinc.sty` lead me to website where my browser had some doubt about my personal security ([link](https://svn.kwarc.info/repos/arXMLiv/trunk/sty/XTocinc.sty)).
- But there is also a GitHub result which looks less hostile :) ([link](https://github.com/coyarzun89/MemoriaAndroid/blob/master/xtocinc.sty)).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Content of `XTocinc.sty`:

```
% -------------------------------------------------------------------
% Include Table of Contents in the Table of Contents
% Change spacing
% Modified by Alex, October 1994
% Bug Fix: TOC Page number when TOC spans over one page (November, 1999)
\newlength{\tclineskip}
\setlength{\tclineskip}{\baselineskip}
\def\@addcontentsline#1#2#3{\if@filesw \begingroup
\let\label\@gobble \let\index\@gobble \let\glossary\@gobble
\def\protect##1{\string\string\string##1\string\space
   \space}\@temptokena{\thepage}%
\edef\@tempa{\immediate\write
\@auxout{\string\@writefile{#1}{\protect
     \contentsline{#2}{#3}{\the\@temptokena}}}}\@tempa
   \if@nobreak \ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi\endgroup\fi}
\def\tableofcontents{\@restonecolfalse\if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
 \fi\chapter*{Table of Contents\@mkboth{CONTENTS}{CONTENTS}}
  \newlength{\@defbaselineskip}
  \setlength{\@defbaselineskip}{\baselineskip}
  \setlength{\baselineskip}{\tclineskip}
  %\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
  \@starttoc{toc}
  \setlength{\baselineskip}{\@defbaselineskip}
  \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
  \relax}
% -------------------------------------------------------------------
```

- Download the file and place it in the same folder as the rest.

### Finally...

Now you can start your document...

Comment: Are you allowed to distribute the file under a different license?

Comment: Just because you can see stuff on github, does not mean you can use te stuff for any purpose.

Comment: I don't know. .